# Java store xml file contents into a string

Tags: java, xml, string, file

I have a static method that creates an xml file and I would like it to return the raw xml file as a string. After creating the xml file I would like to read from the file and convert it to a string. How do I go about doing so?

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a variety of ways of doing it:

- [How to create a Java String from the contents of a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326390/how-to-create-a-java-string-from-the-contents-of-a-file)

Answer (score 2):

http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html

```
Joiner.on('').join(Files.readLines(file, CharSet.fromName("UTF-8")))
```

Comment: just make sure the charset specified matches the xml file, or you will corrupt the file.

Answer (score 1):

you could turn to, for the file handling, to the apache.commons.io library.

This one has build in convenience functions for reading and storing files.

So for reading

```
org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils#readFileToString(File file)
```

and for writing

```
org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils#writeStringToFile(File file, String data)
```

See here for javadoc
http://commons.apache.org/io/